# jQuery CSS HTML Network (node) diagram

Tags: jquery, diagram

I am looking for, hopefully, a plugin to achieve this design: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHnFg.png

I don't know too much about svg graphics so creating that way may be a little tough for me. The nodes are hard coded so it doesn't have to support dynamic data.

Any tutorials, links, plugins are appreciated! I've looked into a multitude of plugins but I cannot find one I can hack together to make what I need. Would going the d3.js route and making my own chart be difficult?